# How do I access the created NestJS ApplicationContext within Imported Modules/Controllers?

Tags: nestjs

I'm relatively new to NestJs and am wondering how can I access the INestApplication application context created in my server bootstrap from an imported Module or Controller? I'm building a framework on top of NestJS and need access to lists of specific types components/services etc that have been provided by my framework as well as applications written with the framework.

Comment: > I'm relatively new to NestJs [...] I'm building a framework on top of NestJS --- Are you sure this is a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

1. **For Modules**, you are unable to do that since they will be invoked before the ApplicationContext will get bootstrapped. What might help, depending on your case, are [Dynamic Modules](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/dynamic-modules#dynamic-modules).
2. **For Controllers**, you can use the [ModuleRef](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/module-ref#module-reference), which allows you to dynamically import anything from the ApplicationContext.

Very important to note is the `{ strict: boolean }`-option

```js
onModuleInit() {
  // Will search only inside the ModuleContext
  this.service = this.moduleRef.get(Service);
  // Will search in the whole application
  this.service = this.moduleRef.get(Service, { strict: false });
}
```