# nestjs can't access to the application-context's module-dependency graph

Tags: typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I would like to serve the app's module dependency graph dynamically in my application, using [nestjs-spelunker](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nestjs-spelunker).

That means, to be able to call `SpelunkerModule.explore(app)` (where `app` is the built application context created by calling `NestFactory.create`) on each request to my controller.
but after reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52772353/how-do-i-access-the-created-nestjs-applicationcontext-within-imported-modules-co) I understand it might not be possible to inject the app context.

As an alternative, I thought about calling the `SpelunkerModule.explore(app)` in my `main.ts`, immediately after the app is being created, and inject the result somehow to some built module, or maybe dynamically create new module and inject it to the app.

I can't figure out how to do nither of those solutions.

I tried to create a dynamic module, with a `forRoot` static creation function, but I don't know how to add this module to the already built app (I have to create this dynamic module only after the app has been created to have its dependency graph fully built).

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is a hacky one: leverage on `app.use(middlewareFn)` at `main.ts` after calling `SpelunkerModule.explore(app)` to define a middleware that will attach the module-dependency graph object to the request object